# Clarifying Parkinson Python Code

Tags: volatility, programming

I would appreciate opinions/reviews on whether my python code to calculate Parkinson Volatility index is correct. Thank you very much!

```
def parkinson(price_data, window=WINDOW, trading_periods=N, clean=True):
    rs =  (price_data['high']/price_data['low']).apply(np.log) ** 2.0
    def f(v):
        return (1.0 / (4.0 * math.log(2.0)) * trading_periods * v.mean()) ** 0.5
    result = rs.rolling(window=window, center=False).apply(func=f)
    
    if clean:
        return result.dropna()
    else:
        return result
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: hi, I don't think this is the right platform for code reviews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are multiplying by `v.mean()` and you are missing the sum of squared differences for the rolling window. I did this quickly, off the top of my head, so you may want to double-check.

I don't see why the nested function, the use of pandas.apply(), or `center=False` (default pandas behavior) is necessary, so I got rid of those. I made some other adjustments, too, that were more intuitive for me.

```
def parkinson(price_data, window=WINDOW, trading_periods=N, clean=True):

    const = 4.0 * np.log(2.0)

    # sum of squared differences
    rs = (np.log(price_data['high'] /
                 price_data['low']) ** 2.0).rolling(window=window).sum()

    result = (rs / (const * trading_periods)) ** 0.5
    
    if clean:
        return result.dropna()
    else:
        return result
```

Just to be sure we are on the same page, this is the formula I'm replicating in Python here:

$${Parkinson's Vol} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4\ln(2)N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ln\left(\frac{H_i}{L_i}\right)^2}$$

I hope this helps.